# What is the reverse of the Modulo operator

Tags: javascript, modulo

I have hard time wrapping my head around how to get this to work so I came to ask the help of the brilliant minds in here.

The thing is, I want to reverse the process of the below equation so that I get  ***`X`*** from the given ***`Y`*** and ***`Z`***.

```
Z = [ ( X * 30 ) % Y ]
```

For the use-case, a user inputs number `Y` and then presses <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the system get's the current server time and then multiplies that by 30. The user will then be given the remainder of the server time in format `HHMMssxxx`, *(hmm, `xxx` here is the millisecond.. I don't know the format letter for millisecond.. hehe..)*, divided by `Y` - that is `(X*30) % Y` where `X` is the current server time converted to int.

How can I do this in reverse?

The catch is, `X` should not be greater than `2359999` -> (23:59:59.999) the maximum time value for a 24-hour clock.

Supposedly I have `Z = 32, Y = 400`, how can I find `X`?

I know that it's possible to have multiple answers. Here's what I came up so far but I think this is not very optimal in terms of performance.

```
function getTimeIDx(rem, codeIndexer) {
    var times = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 2400000; i++) {
        if((i * 30) % codeIndexer == rem) {
            var str = i.toString(),
                l = str.length;

            if(l < 9)
                str = '000000000'.substr(0, 9 - l) + str;

            str = str.substr(0, 2) + ':' + str.substr(2, 2) + ':' + str.substr(4, 2) + '.' + str.substr(6);

            if(/^(?:[0-1]?\d|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5]?\d):(?:[0-5]+\d)/.test(str))
                times.push(str);
        }
    }

    return times;
}
```

Is there some way to do this more efficiently? Is there something like a inverse modulo?

**EDIT:**

Updated code to check if the string is a valid time.

Comment: If you could reverse it, you would be the most powerful person in the world.

Comment: that question would also be good for https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: yeah, thanks.. ill try posting it there.

Comment: @JonasW., how about the code above? that will still return something. Looks correct to me though it gives multiple answers. Am I powerful now? :D

Answer (score 3):

You cannot reverse it. Modulo is the remainder from a division operation.

Simplifying your equation.  Z =  Y % 2

Z is 0 for half of the values and 1 for the rest.

You can not solve for the dividend with just the remainder and the divisor.

Comment: ***"`X` should not be greater than 2359999."*** and ***"I know that it's possible to have multiple answers."***

Comment: Updated code to check if the string is a valid time.

Answer (score 3):

Lets fill it into the equation:

```
 32 = ( X * 30 ) % 400
```

Then this means that `X * 30` is a multiple of 400 plus 32:

```
 32
 432
 832
 ...
```

Now we could divide that by 30 to get x. That could be done in js like this:

```
 function* reverse(Z, Y) {
  for(let n = 0; ; n++)
    yield (Z + Y * n) / 30;
}
```

Usable as:

```
 for(let X of reverse(32, 400))
   console.log(X);
```

Note that this loop will run forever as there are infinite results. [Try it](http://jsbin.com/bazibibawo/edit?console)

Comment: lol. i wont try it since you said it would yield infinite results

Comment: I've also added that the answer shouldnt be greater than 2359999

Comment: Updated code to check if the string is a valid time